# Angular component opacity does not work anymore when using Bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

In my Angular application, I have two components, A and B, the first is a toggle button and the second is a form. B component subscribes to the state of the A component using a service in order to set its CSS according to the observed toggle state. For example, if the A component is set to state 'leftPressed', the component B reacts to this state setting its own CSS to 'enable' (through [ngStyle]) in order to make the form usable by the user, instead if the A component is set to the state 'rightPressed' the B component sets its own CSS to 'disable'. This is the code of the CSS disable style:

```
.disable {
  opacity: 30%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This strategy will opacize the form and make the same form not clickable by the user.
My problem is that this thing worked until I introduced in my project Bootstrap in order to make my application more responsive (I have just placed these two buttons in the div-row-col scheme according to the Bootstrap modus operandi), but the strange thing is that only the opacity does not work on the B component but the 'mouse-event: none' worked as expected.

How can it be possibile that a CSS, in that case, is valued partially? The only thing I know is that if I roll back putting those components in my previous HTML without Bootstrap code, everything works fine.

Update with more code:

This is the code of my HTML component in which is declared more components

```
<!--This is the bar without Bootstrap that works-->
<div class="searchBar">
  <app-button-search-city-polygon-component></app-button-search-city-polygon-component>
  <app-search-city-bar [ngClass]="[cityBarStyle]"></app-search-city-bar>
  <app-clear-polygon-bar [ngClass]="[polygonBarStyle]"></app-clear-polygon-bar>
  <app-button-search-centers-or-operators></app-button-search-centers-or-operators>
  <app-validate-and-search-button></app-validate-and-search-button>
</div>

<!--This is the bar developed using Bootstrap and the CSS opacity DOES NOT WORK on the component 'app-search-city-bar'-->
<div class="searchBar row align-content-lg-center">

  <div class="col-lg-1">

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <app-button-search-city-polygon-component></app-button-search-city-polygon-component>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <app-search-city-bar [ngClass]="[cityBarStyle]"></app-search-city-bar>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <app-clear-polygon-bar [ngClass]="[polygonBarStyle]"></app-clear-polygon-bar>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <app-button-search-centers-or-operators></app-button-search-centers-or-operators>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <app-validate-and-search-button></app-validate-and-search-button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-1">

  </div>

</div>
```

This is the CSS of this component:

```
.searchBar {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cityBarDisabled {
  opacity: 30%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.polygonBarDisabled {
  opacity: 30%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cityBarEnabled {

}

.polygonBarEnabled {

}
```

This is the TS code:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {ToggleCityPolygonService} from '../../_service/toggleCityPolygonService/toggle-city-polygon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.css']
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {

  state = '';

  cityBarStyle = '';
  polygonBarStyle: '';

  constructor(private toggleCityPolygonService: ToggleCityPolygonService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.toggleCityPolygonService.getCityPolygonStateObs().subscribe(v => {this.state = v[''];
    // console.log('i\'m gettin value: ' + v);
    if (v === 'searchByCity') {
      // @ts-ignore
      this.polygonBarStyle = 'polygonBarDisabled';
      this.cityBarStyle = 'cityBarEnabled';
    } else {
      if (v === 'searchByPolygon'){
        this.cityBarStyle = 'cityBarDisabled';
        // @ts-ignore
        this.polygonBarStyle = 'polygonBarEnabled';
      }
    }
    })
  }

}
```

The 'toggleCityPolygonService' is the service which holds the 'cityPolygonState' that change between two values when the user click on the relative toggle button which can assume only two states: 'searchByCity' and 'searchByPolygon'

Comment: Can you add more code!!

Comment: Show image, code snippet to know more about issue.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity takes value 0.1 - 1. Try changing opacity: 30% to opacity: 0.3;
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: Have you tried using devtools to check if it sees your class? If it sees it, maybe you’ll need to set !important .... also in your ngClass; try [ngClass]=“v===‘yourString’ ? ‘class1’ : ‘class2’” . Note that you’ll have to set store v from your subscription in a variable. No point doing the iteration in your ts when ngClass can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the issue caused by Bootstrap. It's because of css optimiser ([cssnano](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/)) on production build.

To avoid this, you can use the values between 0 and 1.
In your case, you can use 0.3 instead 30%.

```
opacity: 0.3; // opacity: 30%;
```

[MDN guild on opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)
Issue reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17440)